# Why do authors write mathematical expressions in their books?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, mathematics

I'm currently interested in and new to QM and I'm reading a book, that teaches QM in an easy way. But there are many mathematical expressions about various things, like the quantum state of a spin when an apparatus is rotated along the x-, y- or z-Axis.

I can think of what the purpose of these expressions might be, but I want to know it more clearly.

What's the purpose of writing these mathematical expressions and do I really have to know/understand every single detail of these expressions or just generally know what they are?

Thank you !

PS: I'm currently not studying physics, but I'm thinking of studying physics in the future. ^^

Comment: *What's the purpose of writing these mathematical expressions [...]?*- Well, long story short: Mathematics is the 'language' of physics. So in order to properly understand the physics it is necessary (I think most of the physicist would argue) to understand the maths; at least to an certain extend. Whether you should know every single detail is another story. But what is your question, actually? It seems that it is not about physics and thus could be off-topic.

Comment: you need to learn the mathematical language and how it works. Otherwise I advice  you   a popular science book instead.

Comment: @Jakob Thx for the answer. I just wanted to know it more clearly.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny thx

Comment: Learning physics involves mathematics, there is no way around it. Equations describe a concept that cannot be described with words, or at least, cannot be accurately be described with words. It is one of the things that make mathematics beautiful. Mathematics is an entire language that needs to be learned, just like any other language. If you cannot learn or are avoiding learning the math of physics, then you will never understand the subject. I recommend a free course called Introduction to Mathematical Thinking offered by Stanford: https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you never have learned physics before. And before diving into QM and the like, you have to learn the basics first. Start with Mechanics and then do the research to find out what other subjects you need to learn before you move on to the more advanced stuff. Don't start your first physics experience with quantum mechanics, that is a very bad idea! Also, make sure that you have strong math background as well. Aways research the prerequisites for the subject and learn them. I recommend Khan Academy for the math and beginner physics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematics has some very useful properties that make it superior to natural language in describing physical theories:

1. **It is precise**: an English sentence can be ambiguous and can be interpreted in wrong ways. A mathematical statement, when every term is well defined, can mean only one thing.
2. **It is coincise**: the author of your book could ramble on and on about how the wave function behaves, how it evolves in different cases etc.. or they could just write down the Schrodinger equation. The single equation contains every possible case of every possible wave function, with no ambiguity. Of course, the difficult part is to solve the equation.
3. **It can describe the world**: which is a non trivial property. Many physical processes (maybe all of them?) can be described with a mathematical theory.

This makes mathematics an invaluable tool for the physicist, especially in the context of quantum mechanics, where our common intuition fails.

Comment: I just want to add that in addition to being a language, mathematics provides a *logical system of deduction.* In this sense it is more powerful than an ordinary language; in addition to formulating statements precisely, mathematics can tell us when two statements are equivalent, or when one follows from the other, or in contradiction... etc.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of physics is to produce consistent models of nature. Consistency requires that such models be formulated in mathematical terms. Experiment is needed to determine that a consistent model indeed represents nature or aspects of nature.